# How to log data into a text file with an overwrite option and not appending to the EOF with minicom OR gtkterm in Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port

I know how to log/capture the data into a text file, but on multiple runs with the same pipe open, it appends the new data to the end of the file. I cannot find an option to overwrite the existing data on subsequent runs (writing over the old data) instead of appending it to the previous data (adds the new data at the end of the file). Does anyone know a way to do this, or a serial communication terminal that can?

Comment: Can you show some example commands you're running and how the file is being appended to? You can always write a script to truncate the file before you run the command, e.g. `: > logfile`, assuming `logfile` is the name of the file you want to truncate.

Comment: In minicom, I use the -C filename method to write to a file.

I run my program, it writes data to it. When I run the program again, it writes the new data at the end of the file. Nothing to show really. I could write a script that truncates the old data but I am hoping for an option within these two popular tools. I've seen other comm terms have an append or overwrite option when dumping to a file.